# pythonic way to create 3d dict

Tags: python

I want to create a dict which can be accessed as:

```
d[id_1][id_2][id_3] = amount
```

As of now I have a huge ugly function:

```
 def parse_dict(id1,id2,id3,principal, data_dict):
        if data_dict.has_key(id1):
           values = data_dict[id1]
           if values.has_key[id2]
              ..
        else:
            inner_inner_dict = {}
             # and so on
```

What is the pythonic way to do this?

note, that i input the principal.. but what i want is the amount..
So if all the three keys are there.. add principal to the previous amount!

Thanks

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You may want to consider using [`defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html):

For example:

```
json_dict = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(dict))
```

will create a `defaultdict` of `defaultdict`s of `dict`s (I know..but it is right), to access it, you can simply do:

```
json_dict['context']['name']['id'] = '42'
```

without having to resort to using `if...else` to initialize.

Answer (score 7):

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(lambda : defaultdict(dict))

d[id_1][id_2][id_3] = amount
```

Answer (score 5):

You can make a simple dictionary that creates new ones (using [Autovivification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autovivification)):

```
>>> class AutoDict(dict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        x = AutoDict()
        self[key] = x
        return x

>>> d = AutoDict()
>>> d[1][2][3] = 4
>>> d
{1: {2: {3: 4}}}
```

This will have no limit of dimensions as the defaultdict with dict has.

Or a simpler version using `defaultdict` (from the above wiki link):

```
def auto_dict():
    return defaultdict(auto_dict)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> import json

>>> def tree(): return defaultdict(tree)

>>> t = tree()
>>> t['a']['b']['c'] = 'foo'
>>> t['a']['b']['d'] = 'bar'
>>> json.dumps(t)
'{"a": {"b": {"c": "foo", "d": "bar"}}}'
```

Comment: I had always been meaning to look into json manipulation, but I put it off for other small projects out of fear. This is a really clear example. It's great to see alternative solutions, in case I might need to make a 4-d or more dictionary. (At one time, I figured all I'd need was a 2-d dictionary.)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to have a look at multi-dimensional arrays - for example in numpy:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.ndarray.html