# how can I add dictionaries in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, scrapy

I have 4 items.

```
item['bigCtgr'] = 'item'
item['smaCtgr'] = 'food'
item['ssCtgr'] = 'apple'
item['sCtgr'] = 'red'
```

and i will add to process_item many times.
so i want to make structure like this.
Something like category

```
{"item" : 
    {"food":
        {"apple":
            {"green":NULL},
            {"red":NULL}}, 
        {"banana":
            {"yellow":NULL},
            {"green":NULL}},
    }
    {"sweet":
        {"candy":
            {"yellow":NULL}}
    }
}
```

but my code is not working and I don't know why.

```
class CategoryPipeline(object):
    global ctgr
    ctgr = {}

    def __init__(self):
        global file
        file = open("test.json","w")

    def process_item(self, item, spider):

        if item['bigCtgr'] not in ctgr.keys():
            ctgr[item['bigCtgr']] = {item['smaCtgr']: {item['ssCtgr'] : {item['sCtgr'] : 'NULL'}}}
        if item['smaCtgr'] not in ctgr[item['bigCtgr']].keys():
            ctgr[item['bigCtgr']][item['smaCtgr']] = {item['ssCtgr']: {item['sCtgr'] : 'NULL'}}
        elif item['ssCtgr'] not in ctgr[item['bigCtgr']][item['smaCtgr']].keys():
            ctgr[item['bigCtgr']][item['smaCtgr']][item['ssCtgr']] = {item['sCtgr'] : 'NULL'}
        else:
            ctgr[item['bigCtgr']][item['smaCtgr']][item['ssCtgr']][item['sCtgr']] = 'NULL'


    def __del__(self):
        b = json.dumps(ctgr, ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf-8')
        file.write(b)
        file.write('\n')
        file.close()
```

How can i make the code?

Comment: Not clear,  Do you want the vales as `NULL`  , what is the significance of `bigCtgr` etc

Comment: I just want to make Hierarchy structure using only dictionaries..

Comment: Can you give it as sample input and expected output so I could better to test it and try to give you an answer

Comment: The expected result as Shown here is not a valid dict

Comment: See if this helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12167192/pythonic-way-to-create-3d-dict

Comment: @Sarathsp i edit my question.. thank you

Comment: `{"item" : {{"food":{"apple":{"green":NULL},{"red":NULL}}, {"banana":{"yellow":NULL},{"green":NULL}},{"sweet":{"candy":"yellow"}}}}`
 is not avalid `dict`

Comment: Are you trying to make a tree or something ?

Comment: yes, i want to make like tree using json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I implemented a tree with dict and `__missing__` function. This adds nodes if it does not exist

```
import json

class CategoryNode(dict):
    def __missing__(self,key):
        self[key] = CategoryNode()
        return self[key]
    def add_item(self, item):
        self[item['bigCtgr']][item['smaCtgr']][item['ssCtgr']][item['sCtgr']] = CategoryNode()



class CategoryPipeline(object):
    ctgr = CategoryNode()
    file = "test.json"

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        CategoryPipeline.ctgr.add_item(item)

    def json(self):
        json.dump(CategoryPipeline.ctgr,open(CategoryPipeline.file,'w'), ensure_ascii=False,  encoding='utf-8')
```

This is how you may use it

```
cp = CategoryPipeline()
item  = {}
item['bigCtgr'] = 'item'
item['smaCtgr'] = 'food'
item['ssCtgr'] = 'apple'
item['sCtgr'] = 'red'
item2 = {}
item2['bigCtgr'] = 'item'
item2['smaCtgr'] = 'food'
item2['ssCtgr'] = 'Orange'
item2['sCtgr'] = 'orange'
cp.process_item(item,"Yo")
cp.process_item(item2,"Yo")
cp.json()
```

Comment: I have cleaned the code a little also. If it helped you solve the problem accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

and also i found this function

```
class CategoryPipeline(object):
    global inf_dict, ctgr
    inf_dict = lambda: collections.defaultdict(inf_dict)
    ctgr = inf_dict()

    def __init__(self):
        global file
        file = open("test.json","w")

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        ctgr[item['bigCtgr']][item['smaCtgr']][item['ssCtgr']][item['sCtgr']] = 'NULL'


    def __del__(self):
        b = json.dumps(ctgr, ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf-8')
        file.write(b)
        file.write('\n')
        file.close()
```